# sort xml node based on condition

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<Candidate:candidateInfo>
  <Candidate:name> AAA</Candidate:name>
  <Candidate:age>16</Candidate:age>
  <Candidate:sex>M</Candidate:sex>
</Candidate:candidateInfo>
<Candidate:candidateInfo>
  <Candidate:name> BBB</Candidate:name>
  <Candidate:age>28</Candidate:age>
  <Candidate:sex>F</Candidate:sex>
</Candidate:candidateInfo>
<Candidate:candidateInfo>
  <Candidate:name>CCC</Candidate:name>
  <Candidate:age>28</Candidate:age>
  <Candidate:sex>M</Candidate:sex>
</Candidate:candidateInfo>
```

I need to sort the nodes in ascending order of the candidate age.Out of the 3 sorted values, I have to populate all the information from the median (2nd out of 3) element if the corresponding age is greater than 18. Else i have to populate the values from the element 3.

Comment: What output do you need (I'm not clear on "populate all the information"); what code have you tried, what output did it give, and how does this differ from what you need the output to be?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Candidate:candidateInfo[number(Candidate:age) > 18]">
        <xsl:sort-by select="number(Candidate:age)"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Candidate:candidateInfo">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

This filter will remove all candidateInfo elements under the age of 19.